# Bubble Sorting Strings According to Upper Case and Lower Case Letters

Tags: c, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, bubble-sort

I am trying to bubblier sort my 2d array.  Once I get to this point I get memory leaks:

```
te = word[i];
word[i] = word[i+1];
```

Once I get to this point I get a segment fault:

```
   word[i+1]=te;
```

I have tried using `strcpy` to copy the strings but I still get the segment fault error when I use it too.

```
void word_sorter(char** word,int numWord){

        int i =0;
        int j =0;
        for(i = 0; i < numWord; i++){

            for(j = 0; word[i][j] != '\0'; j++){


                        if(word[i][j]>= 'A' && word[i][j] <= 'Z'){

                                 char *te;
                                te =(char*)calloc(10000,sizeof(char));
                                te = word[i];
                                word[i] = word[i+1];
                                word[i+1]=te;



                        }



               }

        }

}
```

I am trying to sort the strings so that capital letters have precedence over lower case letter

```
INPUT: aand AAnd Aand
OUTPUT:AAnd Aand aand
```

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating memory and assigning that address to `te`, then immediately overwriting that value with `te = word[i]`.  This will leak the memory returned by `calloc`.

`word[i+1]` will access past the end of the array on the last iteration of the `i` loop, when `i == numWord - 1`.  This is the source of your segmentation fault.